# Code fails to update a table on BQ using DML, but succeeds for insertion and deletion with RPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I wrote some code that uses service-account to write to BQ on google-cloud.

A very strange thing is that only "update" operation using DML fails. (Other insertion, deletion RPC calls succeeds).

```
    def create_table(self, table_id, schema):
        table_full_name = self.get_table_full_name(table_id)
        table = self.get_table(table_full_name)
        if table is not None:
            return  # self.client.delete_table(table_full_name, not_found_ok=True)  # Make an API
            # request.  # print("Deleted table '{}'.".format(table_full_name))
        table = bigquery.Table(table_full_name, schema=schema)
        table = self.client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
        print("Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id))


#Works!
    def upload_rows_to_bq(self, table_id, rows_to_insert):
        table_full_name = self.get_table_full_name(table_id)
        for ads_chunk in split(rows_to_insert, _BQ_CHUNK_SIZE):
            errors = self.client.insert_rows_json(table_full_name, ads_chunk,
                row_ids=[None] * len(rows_to_insert))  # Make an API request.
            if not errors:
                print("New rows have been added.")
            else:
                print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))

#Permissions Failure
    def update_bq_ads_status_removed(self, table_id, update_ads):
        affected_rows = 0
        table_full_name = self.get_table_full_name(table_id)
        for update_ads_chunk in split(update_ads, _BQ_CHUNK_SIZE):
            ad_ids = [item["ad_id"] for item in update_ads_chunk]
            affected_rows += self.update_bq_ads_status(f"""
                            UPDATE {table_full_name} 
                            SET status = 'Removed' 
                            WHERE ad_id IN {tuple(ad_ids)} 
                            """)
        return affected_rows
```

I get this error for update only:

`User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ABC.`

Comment: Did you check in IAMs if the account you are using have `bigquery.jobs.create` in this project? You can check using [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions). Update might need different permissions than insert or delete.

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will elaborate on my comment.

In GCP you have 3 types of IAM roles.

- [Basic Roles](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles)

> include the Owner, Editor, and Viewer roles.

- [Predefined Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles)

> provide granular access for a specific service and are managed by Google Cloud. Predefined roles are meant to support common use cases and access control patterns.

- [Custom Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles)

> provide granular access according to a user-specified list of permissions.

What's the difference between predefinied and custom roles? If you change (add/remove) permission for a `predefinied` role it will become `custom role`.

Predefinied roles for BigQuery with permissions list can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery)

Mentioned error:

> User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project ABC.

Means that `IAM Role` doesn't have specific [BigQuery Permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bq-permissions) - `bigquery.jobs.create`.

`bigquery.jobs.create` permission can be found in two predefinied roles like:

- BigQuery Job User - (roles/bigquery.jobUser)
- BigQuery User - (roles/bigquery.user)

Or can be added to a different `predefinied role`, however it would change to `custom role`.

Just for addition, in [Testing Permission](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/testing-permissions) guide, you can find information on how to test IAM permissions.

Answer (score -3):

Please give the service account the `bigquery.user` role and try to run the code again.

```
BigQuery Job User
role: bigquery.user
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29941899)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: It does offer an answer. I’d prefer more explanation, but despite the rhetorical question mark, this is clearly offering a solution.

Comment: @JeremyCaney A possible solution that should be checked with more information (clearly indicated by the question) before being presented as an answer on SO, and that's why a verification comment is more at due